# How do we xfail a test case for just one environment, when it runs against multiple environments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

As background, we have test cases that run across 20+ deployments of the same product, and in some of those deployments, test cases fail due to a known bug, and in others, they pass.

Could anyone please help with a suggestion to best 'xfail' a test case for just one particular environment?

We already have access to which environment a particular test run is running against via an `env` fixture, or even a function call. We just need a clean and logical way to xfail tests. We would like to do something like this:

**What we would like (or something similar, with a decorator)**:

```py
@pytest.mark.xfail(envs=["my_env_1", "my_env_18"], reason="Bug/JIRA-TICKET")
def test_my_test_case(...fixtures...):
   # some code
```

**Our current solution**:
This feels very hacky?

```py
def test_my_test_case(env, ...fixtures...):
   if env in ["my_env_1", "my_env_18"]:
      pytest.xfail(reason="Bug/Ticket-Number")
```

Any suggestions welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce your own marker for that purpose. Example:

#### test case

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.myxfail(envs=["my_env_1", "my_env_18"], reason="Bug/JIRA-TICKET")
def test_eggs():
    pass
```

#### analyzing the `myxfail` marker

Add a file `conftest.py` to your project/test root dir with the following contents:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def check_myxfail(request):
    myxfail = request.node.get_closest_marker("myxfail")
    if myxfail is None:
        return

    envs = myxfail.kwargs.get("envs", [])
    if "my_env_1" in envs:
        reason = myxfail.kwargs.get("reason", None)
        pytest.xfail(reason=reason)
```

#### register `myxfail` marker

In the `pytest.ini` config:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    myxfail: xfail the test if env matches.
```

#### sample execution

```
$ pytest -vrx
==================================== test session starts =====================================
...
collected 1 item                                                                             

test_spam.py::test_eggs XFAIL                                                          [100%]

================================== short test summary info ===================================
XFAIL test_spam.py::test_eggs
  reason: Bug/JIRA-TICKET
===================================== 1 xfailed in 0.04s =====================================
```

Of course, you still have to implement the `env` handling yourself. Replace the `if "my_env_1" in envs` condition with your own impl (passing `env` via fixture/command line arg etc).

Comment: Awesome, this definitely works well for our use case. Thank you @hoefling!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness - you can also add a condition directly to `xfail`, e.g:

```
def env():
    return "my_env_1"


@pytest.mark.xfail(condition=env() in ["my_env_1", "my_env_18"],
                   reason='Bug/JIRA-TICKET')
def test_eggs():
    assert False
```

(given the same setup as in the answer by @hoefling).

This produces the same output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
...
collected 1 item

test_setup.py::test_eggs xfail                                           [100%]
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
XFAIL test_setup.py::test_eggs
  Bug/JIRA-TICKET

========================== 1 xfailed in 0.12 seconds ==========================
```

This is admittedly not as nice as the accepted answer, but can be used for simple cases.